# Sending pointers over network considered dangerous?

Tags: c++, pointers, network-programming

I'm storing a set of objects in a `std::vector`, and I have a number of remote procedure call functions that act on these objects.

```
class Particle{...};
std::vector<Particle> particleContainer;

void calledByRPCLibrary(Particle* index){
[Do stuff to *index]
}
```

Currently, I send pointers of objects in the container over the network to serve as an index, avoiding the need for the class to contain an index value and a search function.

The remote programs don't do anything with the pointers - they only echo them back as arguments for remote function calls.

Is this safe - both in general, and with std::vector potentially moving things around?

Comment: A pointer at the other end does not make any sense

Comment: A pointer is only valid in the current process, sending it to another process makes no sense. Also, remember that vectors can be resized when adding elements, making all iterators and pointers to elements invalid.

Comment: I appreciate that, @Ed - It's just a random number at that end, but once it's sent back to the function on the origin machine, it once again refers to something sensible.

Comment: Really- Things may have happened in the meantime. May be a pointer to a different beast but the pointer may still have the same value

Answer (score 1):

Sending pointers into `std::vector` to remote procedure calls is not safe, because if your vector is changing, those pointers become invalid. When you push a new element into `std::vector` and you don't have sufficient capacity, the vector doubles its size, and copies all of its contents to a different memory location. The old pointers are then invalid.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question, however I feel there's an implied follow-up question of *'How do I safely serialise a `std::vector` across a network?`*   To which there are many possible answers, including *Google Protocol Buffers* and *boost.serialization*

Google Protocol Buffers - https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/

boost.serialization - http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html

Both have a lightweight wire format.  Protocol Buffers has the added advantage of portability between programming languages.  Boost is fine just for direct communication between two C++ apps though, particularly if you're already using Boost elsewhere.